# Sort out an NSArray with NSDictionaries into 2 NSArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` with `NSDictionaries`. 
Each of the dictionaries have a key for a BOOL value.

I need to sort through that array and the outcome should be 2 `NSArrays`: one with the dictionaries with the 0 value, and the other with the dictionaries with the 1 value.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 0 value and the 1 value. Could you explain?

Comment: I presumed it meant NO = 0, YES = 1

Comment: Sure. I'll put it into layers. NSArray > NSDictionary > Value for Key that can be a 0 or 1. In other words a BOOL value. So the dictionaries that have this value set to 0 should go to one array, and the ones that have the value set to 1 should go to another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean but:

```
NSMutableArray *yesDicts = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *noDicts = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSNumber *yesorno = dict[@"key"];
    if ([yesorno boolValue] == YES) {
        [yesDicts addObject:dict];
    } else {
        [noDicts addObject:dict];
    }
}
```

where `array` is the initial array, and the BOOL value in each dict is stored at `@"key"`.
Also it uses the new dictionary access syntax

Comment: `dict[@"key"]` is this equal to this `[dict objectForKey@"key"]` ?

Comment: In that case, I think it should do what I need. I'll try it right now

Comment: Super. It does exactly what I needed. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

I think the "best" way is using `NSPredicates`, for example:

```
NSPredicate *yesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"key", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
NSArray *filteredYESResults = [allResultsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:yesPredicate];

NSPredicate *noPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"key", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
NSArray *filteredNOResults = [allResultsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:noPredicate];
```

Comment: surely that's a bit overkill for something this trivial, and is going to be more work for the system to do?

Comment: Small correction: The first format (for the key) must be `%K`, not `%@`.

Comment: Hi tkanzakic, thanks for your reply. However I found iain's answer easier to understand for my current objective-c level (which is just a bit above n00b :))

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc no problem, I just give you an other option ;)